# regex pattern match in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

I've the below XSL template

```
<xsl:template match="para">
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\d+(?=[-, \d]*$)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
             <xsl:variable name="prent">
         <xsl:for-each select="document('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\SG\Commentary_SG_XML-03032014\SG-Singapore Precedents of Pleadings\title.xml')/entry/file">
                                   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\SG\Commentary_SG_XML-03032014\SG-Singapore Precedents of Pleadings\',./@name))//chapter/title[//page/@num=regex-group(1)])"/>
</xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name="cha">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($prent,'CHAPTER '),' ')"/>
                                </xsl:variable>    
<xsl:variable name="size">
<xsl:value-of select="string-length($cha)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="conct">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$size>'1'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#SPPR_CH_',$cha,'/pg_',regex-group(1))"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#SPPR_CH_0',$cha,'/pg_',regex-group(1))"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
 <a href="{$conct}">

        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
 </a>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

and below XML

```
<para>this is 1989 representing text 245</para>
<para>this is sample text 235</para>
<para>this is 234 sample text with comma seperator 345,756</para>
```

when i run this it is throwing me an error as below.

```
Invalid regular expression '\d+(?=[-, \d]*$)' -   Details: -     XTDE1140: The effective value of the 'regex' attribute of the <xsl:analyze-string> instruction must conform to the required syntax for regular expressions
```

here what i'm trying to achieve is, to get the number at the end of the text, ignoring any other characters, when i tested the regex, it is working fine. and it is [here](http://regex101.com/r/oK9uT5), but when i implement the same in my XSLT, it is throwing me an error.

The expected output is

```
<a href="245"/>
<a href="235"/>
<a href="345"/>,<a href="756"/>
```

please let me know how can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Your regex uses a look-ahead assertion which isn't supported in XSLT.

Comment: Hi @nwellnhof, yes you are right, can you please let me know how to modify it and support XSLT. Thanks